# Extract javascript from JSP to JS file

Tags: javascript, plugins, intellij-idea

I'm trying to refactor parts of our front-end at the moment, using Intellij. We have a lot of javascript that is within our JSPs. I'd like to be able to extract from the JSP into a .js fil and replace it with a script tag referencing that file. I know how to extract to an 'includes' file, but I'd like a way of extracting and replacing the code with a proper script tag.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can accomplish this quickly and easily? (Or a pre-existing function in Intellij that I'm unaware of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please [vote for this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-40826) (it's 5 years old and had zero votes).

Answer (score 0):

just create one file with .js extension copy and paste your js codes with their function names. then include that file in your jsp project header section.

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

thats all..

Comment: I'm just looking for the quickest way to do this, such as a keyboard shortcut or something. I know I can copy and paste the code into a file.